# React included script data not recognized

Tags: reactjs

I have a React setup with an index.html page which includes a JavaScript file defining a simple variable:

```
var pData = {};
```

Inside my index.js file I tried to access this variable in a simple way:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <App presData={ pData }/>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

But after running `npm start` this does not compile because it says `'pData' is not defined`.

When I add some debug I get something really strange to me:

```
var testData;
if (typeof pData === "object") {
    testData = pData; // Fails on this line because pData is not defined!
} else {
    alert("Typeof pData inside index.js: " + (typeof pData));
}
```

The above code fails because the variable is not defined inside a code block that is only executed when the variable is defined as an object.

How is this possible, and how do I get access to this variable inside the React file?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Paul

Answer (score 1):

You can use `window.pData = {};` it will be available but it's not a good practice. If you're using ES6 with babel you can import your variable with `import`.

myData.js

```
var pData = {};
export default pData;
```

index.js :

```
import pData from './myData.js';

ReactDOM.render(
  <App presData={ pData }/>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because your js file is include in html, so When staring compile, index.js doesn't know where `pData` defined.

Let's say the code `var pData = {};` is in a file named data.js, and it's in the same folder with index.js, try

```
import './data.js';
```

at first line in  index.js file;